# Can anyone help identify this Japanese font from Haikyuu?

Tags: font-identification, japanese

I was asked to create a poster with a similar font from ‘The Way of Ace’ in Haikyuu! I have a hard time identifying this Japanese font, may I ask if anyone knows which font this is?

The typical font identifying sites does not seem to identify Japanese properly, and I also tried

https://ja.m.likefont.com/
Reddit: identifythisfont

[image: The Way of Ace - Haikyuu!!]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Some characters appear to be repeated, and these are not identical. So this suggests it's not a font, but probably hand drawn letters.

Comment: That’s why! Thank you so much Billy!

Comment: It might be worthwhile finding someone who can do Japanese calligraphy in a similar style, then you could scan it and use it in your project.